# Signing an office new lease during the 3 weeks

Tags: tisha-bav, three-weeks

Is there any prohibition or recommendation in halacha regarding signing an office space lease during the three weeks? If so, where?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you ask because you know one should not purchase a new house during the three weeks. The rationale is that one should not say the blessing of *she'hechiyanu* during that period (for more details see e.g., [here](http://etzion.org.il/en/bein-ha-metzarim-laws-three-weeks) under She-hechiyanu).

Since signing an office lease is not a purchase, it doesn't require a *She-hechiyanu*, and therefore I do not see why it would be forbidden for at least three reasons

- it resembles a business transaction which is allowed (e.g., see [here](http://dinonline.org/2017/07/18/buying-a-new-apartment-as-an-investment-during-the-3-weeks/) regarding buying an apartment as a financial investment)
- YUTorah ([here](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/735559/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/halachos-of-the-three-weeks/), V.1.B) also quotes R Moshe Feinstein that one may buy a new car or truck for business as this would be included in the category of minimizing business transactions, which we are lenient with nowadays
- if delaying the signature would cost money, it turns the matter from a pleasurable activity to avoiding a loss which also makes it permitted (see e.g., end of [here](http://www.aish.com/atr/3-Weeks-9-Days-Home-Purchase.html)).

As always, please [ask your rav](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) before applying anything you read here in practice.